# xamarin.ios binding objective-c union | Marshalling custom types

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, struct, xamarin.ios

Good day to everyone!
I've faced with an issue while working on creation binding project for  Objective-C framework.
I have following struct definition in Objective-C:

```
typedef struct {
SCIDataType type;
union {
    char charData;
    short int16Data;
    int int32Data;
};
} SCIGenericType;
```

And here is the C# code in my Structs.cs file in Binding project:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCIGenericType
{
    public SCIDataType type;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Data
    {
        public sbyte charData;
        public short int16Data;
        public int int32Data;

    }
    public Data data;
}
```

The problem I've got is when I use the generated .dll (from my binding project) in test single-page ios application, I receive following error

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: The registrar cannot marshal the parameter type 'SCIGenericType' of the parameter 'x'

I suppose, I made a mistake somewhere in C# code. I found this documentation page about binding the structs https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute/
But I didn't find what is the right way of binding the union (that one I have in my Objective C struct definition).
Can anybody help me with that? Should I use FiledOffset attribute, and if yes, then how?

Comment: What does your method signature look like? Normally it would be an `IntPtr` and that is a supported marshaling type.

Comment: It's pretty simple: void AddFunction(SCIGenericType data)

Comment: how about `void AddFunction(IntPtr data)` `Xamarin.iOS` has a fixed list of types that it will marshal and does not provide *custom* marshaling. IntPr will get marshaled to ObjC as a pointer to your struct... This is unsafe C# code of course, so if your struct is not defined properly, ObjC will be reading/writing to memory outside of your managed struct

Comment: Well, you made my day! It works! Thank u so much!
I suppose this should be marked as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Change:

```
void AddFunction(SCIGenericType data)
```

#### To:

```
void AddFunction(IntPtr data)
```

`Xamarin.iOS` has a fixed list of types that it will marshal and does not provide custom marshaling.

`IntPr` will get marshaled to Obj-C as a pointer to your struct...

This is unsafe C# code of course, so if your struct is not defined properly, Obj-C will be reading/writing to memory outside of your managed struct.